# Go app runs fine locally, produces 404 when running goapp serve

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a written a REST API using the **Gorilla mux** package and all data is stored in a MySQL database. I'm using the **go-sql-driver/mysql** package to access it.

When I compile and run the bin directly, it works as expected.

This is my first attepmt at deploying about to google cloud services, so I'm not familair with any special setup thatr needs to occur to make this work.

All code can be found at [cobraclamp/hotswapper-api](https://github.com/cobraclamp/hotswapper-api)

NOTE: I'm aware that the InitDB in main has boilerplate credentials, they are properly set in the local and production projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't trawled through *all* your code, but I guess the problem is you initialise your router in [`main`](https://github.com/cobraclamp/hotswapper-api/blob/master/main.go).

As per the [App Engine go SDK docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/) and the [Gorilla mux docs](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux), you need to do this in an `init()` function:

> Or, for Google App Engine, register it in a init() function:

```
func init() {
    http.Handle("/", router)
}
```

If you don't do this I guess your app will get a 404 for any route.

Comment: Thank-you, I completely overlooked this. It is working as expected now.